# Visual Studio Code doesn't run on Fedora 29

Tags: visual-studio-code

Help me!

Install code-1.26.1-1534444904.el7.x86_64.rpm.
Run the code.
Oops error:

> /usr/bin/code: строка 35:  5714 Segmentation fault      (стек памяти сброшен на диск) ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1 "$ELECTRON" "$CLI" "$@".

Install code-1.25.1-1531323952.el7.x86_64.rpm.
Run the code.
Is OK!

Is there a problem?

Comment: Yes, only version 25 will run  ;-)  what difference is there between v1.25 and v1.26?